# Disable the asp button after first click because it save multiple records in slow connection

Tags: c#, javascript

```
<asp:Button 
         ID="btnUpdate" 
         runat="server" 
         OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" 
         Text="Update" 
         CssClass ="btn" 
         ToolTip="Update" 
         Width="58px" />
```

`This is my code for button, want to use javascript..help plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy to do to prevent the user pressing it twice - here is an example of using JavaScript to hide the button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" 
 OnClientClick="this.style.visibility = 'hidden';"
 Text="Update" CssClass ="btn" ToolTip="Update" Width="58px" />
```

Comment: i have used this script but its not working  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" event="OnClick" for="<%=btnUpdate.ClientID%>">
var vbtnUpdate=document.getElementById ('btnUpdate');
vbtnUpdate.disabled = true;  
vbtnUpdate.value = 'Pls..wait';   
__doPostBack('btnUpdate','OnClick'); 
</script>

Comment: i want to know whether server side onclick and client side onclick getting clash..

Comment: @Anboo - no, that piece of code wont clash. It will run the Client Side Code, ie you can do some confirmation. If the return is true, it will then post to the server. Are you using jQuery ? Makes it alot easier

Comment: $('#buttonId').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});  I found this code..how to use this with asp button.

Comment: @Anboo - thats using jQuery ... refer to this http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/10/06/how-to-disable-an-asp-net-button-when-clicked.aspx  Add in your code-behind `MyButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(MyButton, "").ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

You should do it clientside, using javascript and not using C# code.
Try to Add OnClientClick event on the button and disable it on the event.

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" event="OnClick" for="<%=btnUpdate.ClientID%>">
var vbtnUpdate=document.getElementById ('btnUpdate');
vbtnUpdate.disabled = true;  
vbtnUpdate.value = 'Pls..wait';   
__doPostBack('btnUpdate','OnClick'); 
</script>

Comment: @Ghylath - setting is to Disabled - ASP.Net for whatever reason doesn't post back properly. Need to use another technique